# set time out in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Firefox always loads dynamic images, but IE it just shows images without any dynamic action. what changes I need to do?

JavaScript code from IE view source code:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”
    <!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ 
    if (document.getElementById("safeForm1d3").submitted.value == "false") { 
      document.getElementById("safeForm1d3").submitted.value = "true"; 
      setTimeout('document.getElementById("safeForm1d3").submit()', 100); 
    }else{ 
    document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none"; 
    }/*-->]]>*/
</script>
```

I am using Wicket framework, so real java code is:

```
 static private class SafeSubmitBehaviour extends AbstractBehavior{
    public void onRendered( Component component ) {
      super.onRendered( component );      
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(200);
      buffer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" ><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/\n");
      buffer.append("if (document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value == \"false\") {\n");
      buffer.append("document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value = \"true\";\n");
      buffer.append("setTimeout('document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submit()', 100);\n}else{\n");
      buffer.append("document.getElementById(\"toHide\").style.display=\"none\";\n}/*-->]]>*/</script>");      
      component.getResponse().write(buffer);
    }  
  }
```

html page which loads my dynamic image is:

```
<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
        <img style="display: inline" src="img/load.gif" />
            <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix">
            <input type="hidden" wicket:id="submitted" value="false" />
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Y'know, modern browsers doesn't need all that comment stuff.

Comment: Code in code in code ... we're going to have to go deeper.

Comment: thats part of code, i have changed. but no change in output.

Comment: That's a pretty foul looking piece of code. You need to break it out into functions so it can be analysed properly and verified to work. All the `"`s and `'`s make it practically impossible to know what's going on.

Comment: i have edited and verified, still not getting output.

Comment: There's no sign of any image markup, or anything else like that, in the sample code you posted.  Perhaps you should post more.  It would also help if you would describe in more detail what you mean by "not working".

Comment: modified question, i hope you can understand now. It is very urgent and I am spending 2 days for this issue, can you please help me out.

Comment: Please add more details, the question in it's current state is vague and unanswerable without making considerable assumptions. -1

Comment: also inappropriate JQuery tag...

Comment: that .submitted.value seems wrong

Comment: @Ben then what is the correct value?. i have assigned to true ie submitted.value = "true";

Comment: yes, but what is submitted? You're using submitted as an object like it's already been defined somewhere..

Comment: it is declared in HTML as  <input type="hidden" wicket:id="submitted" value="false" />

Comment: Since you said that `submit()` isn't working, could you provide the html for `safeFormec`?

Comment: check my updated answer also please put up some display name like

Comment: well perhaps some JS issue. i am sorry i use linux so no IE. But i suggest you do using jquery for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: i found solution, timeout period I have specified is 100. in IE after 100 millisecond ie 1/10 of a second animation stops. I increased to 3000 milli seconds.

Comment: Uhm..., 100000 milliseconds ≠ 1 minute, at least not on my clocks. ;-)

Comment: @user755323: Paul has privilege to edit questions and improve it's readability.

Comment: @user755323: yup, once you’ve got enough rep, you can edit other user’s posts. (See near the bottom of [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), under “ Other people can edit my stuff?!”) I noticed your code hadn’t come through properly.

Comment: sorry, i was trying to ask, how to do code formatting? since i tried to put my code inside <code> ....</code>. it didnot work.

Comment: @user755323: sure — you indent code with four spaces. Alternatively, select the code, and click on the curly braces icon above the text field: that indents all the code you’ve selected.

Comment: search on SO with terms *settimeout argument*: **2,837** results.

Comment: What's the isIE() for? You do the same setTimeout for both true and false.

Comment: +1 to Andre Backlund - completely redundant if statement detected!

Comment: isIE for verifying browser Internet explorer. Since my problem is settimeout in IE. It was working fine in FF.

Comment: Just FYI, 1 minute is 60000 milliseconds.

Comment: Why would converting plain JS to jQuery (which is also javascript, hence my modification to your question) help you in any way?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML and also explain what this code is meant to do exactly. I'm not sure why your outputting JavaScript like that in the second code block.

Comment: The code looks okay. Rewriting it to jQuery wouldn't change the functionality much.

Do you get JavaScript errors?

Have you tried using Firebug and inspecting "submitted"? Have you tried putting console.log('submitted', document.getElementById("safeForm1d3").submitted.value) at severeal points in your code to see what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved my problem. may be useful for others:

> Answer:

HTML source code:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    document.getElementById('toHide').style.display ="";
    $('#toHide').doTimeout(1000, function() { 
        $('#toHide').find('#safeForm34').submit(); 
        document.getElementById('myAnimatedImage').src = "../../img/load.gif"; 
        });
</SCRIPT>
```

html:

```
  <div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
    <img src="img/load.gif" id='myAnimatedImage' style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
    <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `setTimeout()` requires your function to be passed as a string or as an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("safeFormec").submit(); }, 100);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but a `;` may be required after `submit()`.

Comment: @Anon shouldn't be required, but will edit it for proper styling :)

Answer (score 3):

Take away the quotes from around your action:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried removing the function call brackets from the end of this line?

```
document.getElementById("safeForm9c").submit()
```

i.e. do this instead:

```
setTimeout(document.getElementById("safeForm9c").submit, 100)
```

You’re telling IE to call the results of `submit()` in 100 milliseconds time, rather than call submit.

Comment: @user755323: can you clarify what you want me to clarify? :) My suggestion is to use `setTimeoutdocument.getElementById("safeForm9c").submit, 100)` instead of `setTimeoutdocument.getElementById("safeForm9c").submit(), 100)`. I’m not sure if that’s actually causing the issue you’re having, but it looks like it might be.

Comment: @user755323: sorry, my bad, I missed out a bracket — I meant `setTimeout(document.getElementById("safeForm9c").submit, 100)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you detach the submit method from the context of the form (as you do by passing it to another function), then it won't work when it is executed as it depends on `this` being the form that it will operate on (which is why `document.createElement('form').submit.call(form_with_a_control_named_submit)` works.

Comment: @David: huh! I did not realise that. (Still interested to see if the OP gets a different error message from this code.)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("safeForm9c").submit();}, 100);
```

In the old days a setTimeout complete function was in a string format, but these days we use it this way. Also this way makes is possible to do more things when the timeout is complete.

Comment: "Normally"? No, passing a string is not normal these days. Passing functions is normal. Using a string means it gets evaled, which is slow, hard to debug, and breaks scope.

Comment: That's true, but in all the documentation that you find, you will still see the way with the string. With off course isn't normal these days.

Comment: Not in [the documentation I always look at first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout), it does mention using strings, but they are second place.

Comment: almost all documentation that you find :p

Comment: @Joose: 90% of everything is crap, including “documentation”.

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping them inside a function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit(); }, 100);
```

Comment: +1: setTimeout supposed to just have a reference to a function or a string with the function call inside it if you need to provide parameter values.

Comment: when i do this anmiation or dynamic page laoding ie Loding please wait is not happening in IE.

Answer (score 1):

```
function setsubmit()
{
   document.getElementById("safeFormec").submit();
}

setTimeout('setsubmit()',100);
```

Comment: i made this and found that it is working fine, but one issue here i have increased timings to 1000 instead of 100. But Firefox does animation till next page to come, but IE does animation only for a second. how can i make portable?

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
 setTimeout(function() {
        'document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()'
    }, 3000);
```

to...

```
 setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: when i do this I am getting Invalid argument error for Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try doing something like

```
setTimeout('document.getElementById("safeForm9c").submit()', 100);
```

Probably setTimeout accepts the things you want to call as a string, so that it can do an eval after the timeout and run the script as it encouters in the string.

Comment: If use this code then it is not working, earlier my code was same as above. I just modified it to my new code without quotes, itworks in IE with error invalid argument. But in FF anmiation is not happening.

Comment: can you please paste your whole script , with the DOM of the form?

Comment: Don't pass strings to setTimeout. It breaks scope, is slow and makes things hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Include this in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and have

```
 static private class SafeSubmitBehaviour extends AbstractBehavior{
    public void onRendered( Component component ) {
      super.onRendered( component );      
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(200);
      buffer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" >\n");
      buffer.append("var input = $(\"input[name='submitted']\");\n");
      buffer.append("if (input.val() == \"false\") {\n"); 
      buffer.append("  input.val(\"true\");\n"); 
      buffer.append("  setTimeout(function(){ $(\"#").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submit()}, 100);\n"); 
      buffer.append("}\n");
      buffer.append("else {\n $(\"#toHide\").hide();\n}"); 
      component.getResponse().write(buffer);
    }  
  }
```

which should render

```
var input = $("input[name='submitted']");
if (input.val() == "false") { 
  input.val("true"); 
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#safeForm1d3").submit()}, 100); 
}else{ 
  $("#toHide").hide(); 
}
```

Where would you do the `$("#toHide").show();`  ?

Comment: <SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> var input = $("input[submitted]");if (input.val() == "false") { input.val("true"); setTimeout(function(){ $("#safeForm15").submit()}, 100);}else { $("#toHide").hide();}</SCRIPT>                                                     . java script error in IE: Object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: i am getting same errorin IE: Object doesnt support this property or method.  Is it required to include or import jquery? where?

Comment: Yes of course you need to include the framework you are using. Include it in the head like any other external JS file

Comment: can i include js file inside the <script> tag?. is this fine <script wicket:id="jquery-1.3.2" type="text/javascript" src="../../design/scripts/vendor/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: i have tried. java script error is gone. BUT animation is not happening in IE. only it is happening in FF. This is my initial issue.

Comment: I need to see the rendered (view-source) html

Comment: javascript i same as above i have given. view source html: how can attach such a large file?

Comment: A link to the page would be good if allowed - I just want to see the form and the element you click to run the code

Comment: https://admit.belgacom.be/WCE/ESW/selectBundle/productId/hbs_pstn_int_comf     click on this and click new customer.  you will get next page without image shown. but it is production, no changes will be available there.

Comment: but it is not working in IE7 and 6. that is the issue. may be problem with settimeout in IE.

Comment: IE6/7 to your question. I just tested in IE7 mode. No problems. I am sorry I give up. I do not have IE6 and it is likely a WIDGET issue and not a JS issue.

Comment: i am using IE7, but dynamic action is not happening. only it shows next page. it suppose to show dynamic animated action gif file ie animated gif file which is not happening in IE7/8.

Comment: Sorry, which animated gif? I never saw that. It is not in the production?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
img style="display: inline" src="img/load.gif?salt=xxxx"
```

**xxx**: means - a random of an integer.

Maybe, the browser cache the image so it will not repaint. Or you must set the GIF image with loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with adding function call, now images are loading and dynamic, but it never goes to next page or never clear timeout.

code:

```
buffer.append("setTimeout(function(){'document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submit()'}, 100);\n}else{\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var safeForm4d = document.getElementById("safeForm4d");
if ( safeForm4d.submitted.value == "false" ){
   safeForm4d.submitted.value = "true";
   setTimeout(function(){ safeForm4d.submit(); }, 100);
}else{
   document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: var safeForm =document.getElementById("safeForm1da"); if (safeForm.submitted.value == "false") { safeForm.submitted.value = "true"; setTimeout( function(){ safeForm.submit();}, 100); }else{ document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none"; }

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
setTimeout(function(){'document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()'}, 100);
```

is incorrect.  The function you pass there to ".setTimeout()" will do nothing.  Instead of that, try:

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit(); }, 100);
```

The difference is that the actual guts of the function should not have been quoted. In that state, what you've got is a function with a single statement, that statement being a simple string-valued expression.  It would run, but have no effect.

Comment: it goes to next page but in IE it doesnt displays animation or dynamic images. But works fine in FF. This is my real problem.

Comment: You **still** have posted nothing whatsoever to show what it is you're doing with "dynamic images".  The code you posted appears to have something to do with form submission, not images.

Comment: i have updated main source code( on top of this page). please let me know any thing else required

Answer (score 0):

two things:

1. The correct usage of `setTiemout()` is:

   ```
   setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit();
   }, 100);
   ```
2. Your using wicket. The `wicket:id` is nothing the DOM knows. You have to assign an ID and use this one like you did it with the form itself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have modifed setTimeout and tested, still no use.             Wicket will convert to html format.

Comment: now, it is working fine in IE but not woking in FF after changing to:    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit() }, 100);

But in IE it is having an java script error throws.

Comment: Oh! I forgot the `;` at the end of the statement within the function. Tell me what exception you got.

Comment: setTimeout(function(){     document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()};, 100);                                     like this?

Comment: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error] setTimeout(fuction(){document.getElementById("safeFormbc").submit()};, 100);

Comment: No. I updated my solution: `setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit();}, 100);`

Comment: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error] setTimeout(fuction(){document.getElementById("safeFormf3").submit();}, 100);                               i am getting same error after changes also.

Comment: You'r using a `fuction`. Pleas use `function` instead ;)

Comment: i tried that and made to function , it is working fine in FF, no error in FF. But it is not working in IE now, ie animation or dynamic action is not happening but going to next page.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function (){ document.getElementById("safeForm").submit() } , 100);
```

check working example at [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tgjK9/1/).

**CAUTION**:: alert may be irritating.

Comment: when i do this, page is not going to next page. it keep waiting.

Comment: `<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center"> <img style="display: inline" src="img/load.gif" /> <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix"> <input type="hidden" wicket:id="submitted" value="false" /> </form> </div>`

Comment: @experimentX, is a good tool. any other tools are there to identify for Java script CSS error?

Comment: @experimentX I have an issue here in IE, if i use function inside settimeout, animation( or dynamic image changes) is not happening/

Comment: @user706295 well thats just a site that hosts javascript for sharing. well .... i think firebug is the best.

Comment: @experiment, i have made changes as per @Alfred guide as given above, it works fine. but timing issue, IE waits only 3 seconds and FF waits till next page loads. why?

Comment: here i have increased timings to 1000 instead of 100. since it is existing code, I am not sure what/why is 100 value?

Comment: @User75 100 Means 100 milli sec or one/ten sec

Comment: this milliseconds to wait for the page to load?. then why FF waits more than time specified?

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` function throws invalid arguments because whatever the call

```
document.getElementById("safeFormec").submit()
```

returns (some error message maybe) is not a valid argument to `setTimeout` i.e. it can not
be resolved to a function or expression.

The call to `.submit()` fails because there is no action attribute specified for the form (`<form action="somePage.php">`).

Your intention was probably not to do a submit in the `setTimeout` call, but to send the submit function as a value parameter to setTimeout to be executed after a while. Like this:

```
setTimeout(document.getElementById("safeFormec").submit, 100);
```

Note the missing paranthesises.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with time 100 ie 1/10 of second. IE will load images with dynamic action only for for 100 millisecond ie1/10 second and stop. increased time to 3000 and now it is working fine.

> setTimeout(function(){'document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()'},
>   100);

No issues with FF or other browser.

Answer (score 0):

After formatting your initial post I think maybe I found some sources to the problem.

- The function in your timeout is a string.
- You should try and submit the form, not the actual button.

Try this:

```
if (!document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value) {
    document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value = "true";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.forms[0].submit(); // Alt: document.forms['MyFormName'].submit()
    }, 3000);
} else {
    document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: document.forms[0].submit(), what is forms[0]?

Comment: It's a collection in the DOM that holds all the form-elements on the page and using forms[0] selects the first (and usually the only) form on the page. Use the alternative code if you have multiple forms.

Comment: my new code isgiven below. IN IE it is working but having a Javascript error. But strange thing is FF animation is not happening.:   <SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> <!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/if (document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value == "false") {document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value = "true";setTimeout(document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit(), 100);}else{document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";}/*-->]]>*/</SCRIPT>     I am sorry i dnot know how to format here.

Comment: Update your original question, it's easier.

Comment: The problem with above code is that you're not wrapping the content of the setTimeout in a function and therefor it will probably execute instantaneously. Also, why are you wrapping it in CDATA?

Comment: Java script error is Invalid argument. CDATA- it is existing code, i am fixing defect.

Answer (score 0):

This will never give you the desired effect because your **changing from page to page** -- this will cause the aninmation to disappear once the new page starts to load. This will depend on many factors, such as how long the server takes to response, to how fast the user's computer is to re-render the new page.

If you really want this kind of effect to work you should use ajax to send the form data using `.serialize()`, overwrite the current page with the response which should hide the animation.

---

#### Update:

To create the desired effect you'll have to post the form using ajax, then push the new HTML to the DOM.

```
var $form = $('#formId');

$.ajax({
   url: $form.attr('action'),
   type: $form.attr('method'),
   data: $form.serialize(),
   success: function(response) {
    $('#loading').fadeOut(function() {
            // Get only text from the body of the result
        $('body').html($(response).find('body'));
    });
  }
});
```

This is really hacky though and I felt dirty writing that. Seriously. You should really make sure that the response returned isn't go to:

- Reload CSS styles, scripts, etc.
- Any specific title, scripts, styles, etc relevant to that page and search will not appear or be changed.

More than likely you just want to return the result to the query i.e. the search results of the form submitted. In which case just wrap the results in a container and `.find('#container')` instead of `.find('body')`

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes in the setTimeout event:

```
setTimeout('document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()', 100);
```

Change your script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value == "false") {
        document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value = "true";
         if(Wicket.Browser.isIE()) {
             setTimeout(document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit(), 100);
         } else { 
             setTimeout(document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit(), 100);
         }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value == "false") {
        document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value = "true";
        setTimeout('document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()', 100);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well done for spotting the redundant if statement, but your setTimeout "eval" solution is generally considered the bad way to do things - although anyone who argues that it is for performance reasons had better supply real metrics of eval vs closure!!!

Comment: when i do this anmiation or dynamic page laoding ie Loding please wait is not happening in IE

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved my question, may be useful for others:

> Answer:

HTML source code:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    document.getElementById('toHide').style.display ="";
    $('#toHide').doTimeout(1000, function() { 
        $('#toHide').find('#safeForm34').submit(); 
        document.getElementById('myAnimatedImage').src = "../../img/load.gif"; 
        });
</SCRIPT>
```

html:

```
  <div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
    <img src="img/load.gif" id='myAnimatedImage' style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
    <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix" />
</div>
```