# dynamic images are not loading in IE

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set time out in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651668/set-time-out-in-javascript)

i have method settimeout, images are laoding with dynamic action in IE and FF, but it is not going to next page. any problem in my code?

```
       buffer.append("setTimeout(function(){
            'document.getElementById(\"").append(
            component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submit()'}, 100);\n}else{\n");
```

Java script funtion:

```
 if (document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value == "false") {
 document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value = "true";
 setTimeout(function(){'document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()'}, 100);
 }else{
 document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";
 }
```