# dynamic images issue in IE

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set time out in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651668/set-time-out-in-javascript)

i have method settimeout, images are laoding with dynamic action in IE and FF, but it is not going to next page.

```
    static private class SafeSubmitBehaviour extends AbstractBehavior{
    public void onRendered( Component component ) {
      super.onRendered( component );      
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(200);
      buffer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" >\n");
      buffer.append("if (document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value == \"false\") {\n");
      buffer.append("document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value = \"true\";\n");
      buffer.append("setTimeout('document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submit()', 100);\n}else{\n");
      buffer.append("document.getElementById(\"toHide\").style.display=\"none\";\n}]]>*/</script>");      
      component.getResponse().write(buffer);
    }  
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
        <img style="display: inline" src="img/load.gif" />
            <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix">
            <input type="hidden" wicket:id="submitted" value="false" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

how can i solve this? My issue is image with animation is not working IE, but working fine with FF.

Java script funtion from html view source:

```
 if (document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value == "false") {
 document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value = "true";
 setTimeout(function(){'document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()'}, 100);
 }else{
 document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";
 }
```