# image laoding in IE

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set time out in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651668/set-time-out-in-javascript)

i have method settimeout, images are laoding with dynamic action in IE and FF, but it is not going to next page.

```
    static private class SafeSubmitBehaviour extends AbstractBehavior{
    public void onRendered( Component component ) {
      super.onRendered( component );      
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(200);
      buffer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" >\n");
      buffer.append("if (document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value == \"false\") {\n");
      buffer.append("document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value = \"true\";\n");
      buffer.append("setTimeout('document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submit()', 100);\n}else{\n");
      buffer.append("document.getElementById(\"toHide\").style.display=\"none\";\n}]]>*/</script>");      
      component.getResponse().write(buffer);
    }  
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
        <img style="display: inline" src="img/load.gif" />
            <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix">
            <input type="hidden" wicket:id="submitted" value="false" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

how can i solve this? My issue is image with animation is not working IE, but working fine with FF.

Java script funtion from html view source:

```
 if (document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value == "false") {
 document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value = "true";
 setTimeout(function(){'document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()'}, 100);
 }else{
 document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";
 }
```

if I remove function() method from setTimeout, it next page is displaying but images are not dynamic.( dynamic images are like some images infomrs the user to wait for period of time and some animation/dynamic action is happening.)