# invalid arguments for set timeout?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set time out in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651668/set-time-out-in-javascript)

when i run following code in Java script it throws invalid arguments, why?

```
setTimeout(document.getElementById("safeFormec").submit(), 100);
```

HTML

```
<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
  <img style="display: inline" src="img/load.gif" /> 
  <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix"> <input type="hidden" wicket:id="submitted" value="false" /> 
   </form> 
</div>
```