# settimeout in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set time out in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651668/set-time-out-in-javascript)

```
if (document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value == "false") {
    document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value = "true";
    setTimeout(function() {
        'document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()'
    }, 3000);
} else {
    document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";
}
```

It is working fine in FF and other except IE. In IE it wait for 3 seconds then animation stops and goes for page processing ie trying to access next page after 3 seconds.

Suppose If i make timeout is 100000 seconds( ie 1 min), animation or dynamic page loading is happening for 1 min. After 1 min next page processing request and goes to new page.

My requirement is dynamic action or animation should happen till the next page displays and waiting period should be dynamic ie it should clear time if next page is already processed.