# invalid argument and settimeout

Tags: javascript, wicket

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set time out in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651668/set-time-out-in-javascript)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value == "false") {
        document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submitted.value = "true";
        if(Wicket.Browser.isIE()) {
            setTimeout(document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit(), 100);
        } else { 
            setTimeout('document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit()', 100);
        } 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";
    }
</script>
```

When I run it in IE it throws Invalid arguments in IE. FF works fine. I am using Wicket framework.

I added try catch for removing error invalid argument as:

```
if(Wicket.Browser.isIE()) {
    try{ 
        setTimeout(document.getElementById("safeForm4d").submit(), 100);
    }catch(err){}
```

now it is working. But I am not sure why is settimeout in IE is not required of quoets.