# Javascript to jQuery for loading page please wait

Tags: javascript, jquery, wicket

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set time out in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651668/set-time-out-in-javascript)

I am facing lot of problem with this code in IE6 and 7.

To try to eliminate specific JS issues, I would like to know how to convert the plain javascript code below to jQuery code?

html source code is here:

```
 <script type=”text/javascript”>    
        if (document.getElementById("safeForm1d3").submitted.value == "false") { 
          document.getElementById("safeForm1d3").submitted.value = "true"; 
          setTimeout('document.getElementById("safeForm1d3").submit()', 100); 
        }else{ 
        document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none"; 
        }
    </script>
```

I have tried removing quotes from `setTimeout`, or calling inside another function, all are no use. Now i am planning for jQuery, how can i modify to jQuery?

wicket code:

```
 static private class SafeSubmitBehaviour extends AbstractBehavior{
    public void onRendered( Component component ) {
      super.onRendered( component );      
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(200);
      buffer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" >\n");
      buffer.append("if (document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value == \"false\") {\n");
      buffer.append("document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value = \"true\";\n");
      buffer.append("setTimeout('document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submit()', 100);\n}else{\n");
      buffer.append("document.getElementById(\"toHide\").style.display=\"none\";\n}</script>");      
      component.getResponse().write(buffer);
    }  
  }
```

html code:

```
<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
    <img style="display: inline" src="img/load.gif" />
    <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix">
        <input type="hidden" wicket:id="submitted" value="false" />
        </form>
 </div>
```

purpose is loading page, please wait.( with that image load.gif)

can i use $.blockUI? if suppose i want to use these plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/block/
where should I use the code $.blockUI? will my html understand these code?